# Vagrant up fails when installing Theano dependencies, can't fetch index URL

Tags: python, pip, vagrant, theano, conda

Here is the error which has occured:

```
change from absent to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/pip install -q git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git' returned 1:   Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
==> default:   Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement numpy>=1.9.1 (from Theano==1.0.1-81.gf2a2df1)
==> default: No distributions at all found for numpy>=1.9.1 (from Theano==1.0.1-81.gf2a2df1)
```

Comment: which pip version are you using? I think pypi was recently migrated to `pypi.org` from `pypi.python.org` and having up to date pip should make sure everything is smooth

Comment: pip 10.0.0 from miniconda

Comment: can i just edit some file to change the index to pypi.org?

Comment: `10.0.0` sounds good and when I tried `http://pypi.python.org/simple/` from browser it works ok. Sorry, I dont know if I can help here

Comment: @djrtb did you try to download the package.tar on local and than install it?

Comment: try to update Pip: `pip install -U pip`

Comment: or try with --index-url parameter, like this: pip install --index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple/